# Converting timer format hh:mm to decimal format hh.decimal(mm) in Business Objects

Tags: business-objects

The aim is to create a new data column based on a current time formatted colum. 
For example I want to have 4:20 -> 4.33. I can't find a way of manipulating the time format to extract the hours and minutes seperatly to use hours + (minutes / 60).

Any help appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pick specific parts out of a datetime object you need to use the **FormatDate()** function. It returns a string which you need to convert to a number with the **ToNumber()** function before adding the hours and minutes together. So let's create a few variables...

```
Current DateTime=CurrentDate()

Hours=ToNumber(FormatDate([Current DateTime];"hh"); "##")

Minutes=ToNumber(FormatDate([Current DateTime];"mm"); "##")

Hours Minutes Decimal=[Hours] + ([Minutes]/60)
```

If you want to put this all together in one variable you can certainly do that...

```
Hours Minutes Decimal All in One=ToNumber(FormatDate(CurrentDate();"hh"); "##") + (ToNumber(FormatDate(CurrentDate();"mm"); "##")/60)
```

[image]

To locate documentation on what values correspond to which parts of the datetime value do the following...

1. Navigate to the FormatDate() function in the Variable Editor.
2. Click on "More on this function" in the lower right corner.
3. Click on "Custom Formats"

Comment: Is this ths same if it have a column with time data in it? For example if I have [Arrival Time] as a column would it become: `=ToNumber(FormatDate([Arrival Time],"hh"), "##") + (ToNumber(FormatDate([Arrival Time],"mm"), "##")/60)`

Comment: What is the datatype of **Arrival Time**?

Comment: ^^ Thanks for all of that its really useful. I have date and time data so could use `Date Time` which reading about it seems best.

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't seem to work with just time (e.g. Current DateTime=CurrentTime(). However, it does work with CurrentDate() which contains both date and time despite being misleadingly named.

Comment: Is there a way of keeping it in 24 hour time. My current Date Time formatted column is in 24 hour time but the new data is 12 hour i.e 13:30 is becoming 1.5 and it would ideally be 13.5.

Comment: Just done some quick reading and found that "HH" instead of "hh" fixes it :)